# ¿Cómo puedo modificar Información en una base de datos desde java?

Tags: java, sql

Tengo el siguiente problema:

Necesito hacer un método para modificar el nombre de una "Marca" en la base de datos y al hacer click en el botón que estoy configurando me arroja este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

"Indice de columna no valido", la verdad no sé qué parte estoy haciendo mal, les dejo el código que tengo del método `Modificar`:

```
private void btnModificarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             


   if(datosValidos()){   
        try {
            //Registrar driver
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
            //Solicitar conexión  
            String baseDatos = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.202.2:1521:orcl";
            Connection conex = DriverManager.getConnection(baseDatos, "user", "pass");


            String nuevaMarca = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el nuevo nombre de la Marca");

            int codigo = Integer.parseInt(txtCodigo.getText());

            String query = "update Marca " + "set marca='" + nuevaMarca + "'"+ " where codigo=" + codigo + ";";
            PreparedStatement ps = conex.prepareStatement(query);
            ps.setInt(1,codigo);
            ps.setString(2, txtMarca.getText());
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();

            if(rs != null){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Marca actualizada exitosamente");
                btnLimpiar.setEnabled(true);
           }



        } catch (Exception ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());
        }
        txtCodigo.requestFocus();  
    }else
        lblEstado.setText("Tiene errores de validación");

}
```

Comment: podrías agregar la estructura de tu tabla Marca

Comment: Usa `ex.printStackTrace(System.out)` para ver dónde está el error exactamente.

Comment: @Kris Sandoval ya agregue una respuesta. Espero que te sirva

Comment: @Kris Sandoval si una respuesta ha solucionado tu problema, podrías por favor colocar como solucionado. gracias

Answer (score 2):

Hay dos formas de ejecutar un SQL en Java con JDBC.

La primera es que tu montas todo el SQL a mano<sup>1</sup>.

```
"update Marca " + "set marca='" + nuevaMarca + "'"+ " where codigo=" + codigo
```

Ésta sirve tanto con `Statement` como con `PreparedStatement`.

La segunda se puede hacer sólo con un `PreparedStatement`, donde tu montas la query pero sustituyes el valor de los parámetros por ?<sup>2</sup>.

```
"update Marca set marca=? where codigo= ?"
```

Y después haces un `set(Integer|String|Loquesea)` para sustituir el valor de cada parámetro.

En tu código generas el SQL para la primera pero usas luego el `setXXXX`. El método `ps.setInt()` intenta buscar el `?` para hacer la sustituir el valor, pero como el SQL que le pasas no tiene ningún `?`, no lo encuentra y falla.

En general, recomiendo siempre la segunda forma, ya que hace conversión de los parámetros y evita SQL injections.

Además, estás haciendo un update pero llamas a `executeQuery`, lo que no tiene sentido. Deberías hacer `ps.execute`, ya que no se van a devolver resultados.

---

<sup>1</sup> El `;` final sobra.

<sup>2</sup> Nota que ya no hay las comillas alrededor del valor de marca.

Comment: Esto luce como uso de buena práctica, pero no entiendo cómo esto se relaciona al mensaje de error que se muestra en la imagen.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza el error lo lanza porque está construyendo el SQL sin `?` (como si fuera para un `Statement`) y luego hace `ps.setInt(1, codigo)`; como no hay `?` falla.

Comment: Perfecto. Ahora se entiende mejor esta opción.

Answer (score 1):

Tu consulta debería de usar ?. ademas de tus parámetros estaban en orden diferente. Primero la marca y luego el código. Y por ultimo utilizar el método executeUpdate;

Dentro de tu try reemplaza este código:

```
//Registrar driver
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
//Solicitar conexión  
String baseDatos = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.202.2:1521:orcl";
Connection conex = DriverManager.getConnection(baseDatos, "user", "pass");


String nuevaMarca = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa el nuevo nombre de la Marca");

int codigo = Integer.parseInt(txtCodigo.getText());

String query = "update Marca set marca=? where codigo=?";
PreparedStatement ps = conex.prepareStatement(query);
ps.setString(1, txtMarca.getText());
ps.setInt(2, codigo);

// Se ejecuta la consulat de actualizacion.
ps.executeUpdate();

System.out.println("Actualizacion exitosa!!!");

// Se cierra la coneccion.
conex.close();
```